# Why do we usually require $b<a$ in A.M.-G.M. Inequality?

Tags: a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The A.M.-G.M. is sometimes stated as follows.

Let $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers such that $b < a$. Let $a_1 = a$ and $b_1 = b$. Define the sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ recursively for all natural numbers $n\geq 2$ by
$$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n + b_n}{2} \hspace{5mm} \text{and} \hspace{5mm} b_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n b_n}$$
Then we have the inequality for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$b_n \leq b_{n+1} \leq a_{n+1} \leq a_n$$

Why do we require b < a? If $a < b$, I observed that for $n\geq 2$, the above inequality must be rewritten as
$$a < b_n \leq b_{n+1} \leq a_{n+1} \leq a_n < b$$
I couldn't find anything wrong with the assumption $a < b$.

Comment: Correct. There is nothing wrong with what you wrote. You  note the condition $n\ge 2$ is needed if $a<b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a<b$ then

$$a_2=\frac{a+b}{2}$$
and
$$b_2=\sqrt{ab}$$

If $a>b$ then

$$a_2=\frac{b+a}{2}$$
and
$$b_2=\sqrt{ba}$$

So, for $n\ge 2$, the sequence terms do not depend on initial conditions.

$(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are adjacent and the common limit do not depend on $a>b$ or $a<b$.